# Php Как избавиться от множества if

Tags: php, if

Я получаю 3 значения которые могут быть равны low, medium, high каждое. Дальше нужно в зависимости от этих значений вывести число. Всего от 1 до 27. 
Писать через if не красиво. Выходит что то вродь этого.  А как это написать красиво я не пойму.

```
if ($_GET[smile1] == low){
    if ($_GET[smile2] == low){
        if($_GET[smile3] == low){
            echo "1";
        }
    }
}
if ($_GET[smile1] == low){
    if ($_GET[smile2] == low){
        if($_GET[smile3] == medium){
            echo "4";
        }
    }
}
if ($_GET[smile1] == low){
    if ($_GET[smile2] == low){
        if($_GET[smile3] == high){
            echo "7";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А как у вас low-low-high дало значение 7 ? Как тогда кодируются 6 и 8 ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$values = array(
   "low"    => array("low"=>1, "medium"=>2, "high"=>3),
   "medium" => array("low"=>4, "medium"=>5, "high"=>6),
   "high"   => array("low"=>7, "medium"=>8, "high"=>9),
);
$value = $values[$_GET['smile1']][$_GET['smile2']];
```

аналогично для трех ключей - еще один уровень вложенности. Это точно быстрее вложенных `if`-ов и не медленнее, чем `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Работаем как с троичной системой
$num_value = ['low' => 0, 'medium' => 1, 'high' => 2];
// Разряды. smile1 самый "слабый", младший разряд.
$r1 = $num_value[$_GET['smile1']];
$r2 = $num_value[$_GET['smile2']];
$r3 = $num_value[$_GET['smile3']];

// $r1 * 1 - здесь 1 - это 3 в степени 0
// + 1 - здесь 1 - это для поправки, так как в вопросе счёт с 1, а не 0

$value = $r1 * 1 + $r2 * 3 + $r3 * 3 * 3 + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум, так

```
if ($_GET['smile1'] == 'low'){
if($_GET['smile2'] == 'low' && $_GET['smile3'] == 'low'){

    echo "1";

}elseif($_GET['smile2'] == 'low'){

    if($_GET['smile3'] == 'medium'){
        echo "4";
    }elseif($_GET['smile3'] == 'high'){
        echo "7";
    }

}
}
```

Но можно еще оптимизировать.

Answer (score 0):

Может так подойдет?

```
if ($_GET[ 'smile1' ] == 'low' && $_GET[ 'smile2' ] == 'low')
    if     ($_GET[ 'smile3' ] == 'low')    echo "1";
    elseif ($_GET[ 'smile3' ] == 'medium') echo "4";
    elseif ($_GET[ 'smile3' ] == 'high')   echo '7';
```

Comment: Можно еще пробовать `swith( )` или `foreach( )`

Answer (score 0):

Еще как вариант

```
if ($_GET['smile1'] == 'low' && $_GET['smile2'] == 'low') {
    switch ($_GET['smile3']) {
        case 'low':
            echo '1';
            break;
        case 'medium':
            echo '4';
            break;
        case 'high':
            echo '7';
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Троичная система счисления же!

Варианты принимаем как:

- **smile1** - `(0..2) * 3^0`
- **smile2** - `(0..2) * 3^1`
- **smile3** - `(0..2) * 3^2`

Принятые числа суммируем, к результату прибавляем 1

Answer (score 0):

**С циклом**

```
// Работаем как с троичной системой
$num_value = ['low' => 0, 'medium' => 1, 'high' => 2];

// Имена ключей GET запроса. 
// СНАЧАЛА СТАРШИЙ СМАЙЛ!
$smile_name = ['smile3', 'smile2', 'smile1'];

$value = 0;
foreach($smile_name as $k => $smile){
   $r = $num_value[$_GET[$smile]];
   $value = $value * 3 + $r;
}
$value += 1;
```